# Installing ngx-lottie to Angular 17 not working

Tags: angular, lottie, angular17

I've been trying to use ngx-lottie at my Angular 17 app.

I've tried this

```
import { LottieModule } from 'ngx-lottie';

export function playerFactory() { 
  return import('lottie-web'); 
} 

@NgModule({ 
declarations: ['...'],
imports: [ 
   LottieModule.forRoot({ player: playerFactory })
]})
```

But it's says "LottieModule" doesn't exist.

[Github Link](https://github.com/ngx-lottie/ngx-lottie)
I've checked also the documentation at their github account but it looks like they don't support NgModule now because the examples are for stand alone. Correct me if I am wrong or is there any other way to use this at NgModule?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have it in /node-modules ?

Comment: Yes it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation of `ngx-lottie` in angular 17, I followed the [getting started guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-lottie) and it works great!

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import {
  AnimationOptions,
  LottieComponent,
  provideLottieOptions,
} from 'ngx-lottie';
import player from 'lottie-web';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [LottieComponent],
  template: `
    <ng-lottie width="500px" [options]="options"></ng-lottie>
  `,
})
export class App {
  options: AnimationOptions = {
    path: '/assets/animations.json',
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideLottieOptions({
      player: () => player,
    }),
  ],
});
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jdqq4k?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fassets%2Fanimations.json,node_modules%2Fngx-lottie%2Findex.d.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

[reference stackblitz that was used(not by me)!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-lottie?file=src%2Fassets%2Fanimation.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

---

To perform lazy loading, we can use the below code!

```
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideLottieOptions({
      player: () => import('lottie-web'),
    }),
  ],
});
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zo53e4?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fassets%2Fanimations.json,node_modules%2Fngx-lottie%2Findex.d.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

---

for modules please do the below changes!

code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { LottieModule } from 'ngx-lottie';

import player from 'lottie-web';

// Note we need a separate function as it's required
// by the AOT compiler.
// export function playerFactory() {
//   return player;
// }

export function playerFactory() {
  return import('lottie-web');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    LottieModule.forRoot({ player: playerFactory }),
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-lottie-tlgwwp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: I was able to get it working with stand alone but I am using ngModules so I want to implement it there

Comment: I tried that one but it's saying LottieModule not exported at ngx-lottie :(

Comment: @mitokki try to replicate in the stackblitz! or share your github repo